# Integer define in .pch file

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am developing an app in which I need to define in the pch file, so I am using the following code.

```
#define IS_IPHONE5_MAR  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 568) ? 80 : 0
```

Then I get the following error when I use it in the .m file 
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200 + IS_IPHONE5_MAR, 32,32)];

I get the warning 'Operator ?: has lower precedence that +:. + will be evaluated first'. Also I tried the following code in the .pch file. But it gives 'Invalid token at start of preprocessor expressor' error

```
 #define IS_IPHONE5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 568) ? YES : NO
 #if IS_IPHONE5
     #define IS_IPHONE5_MAR 80
 #else
     #define IS_IPHONE5_MAR 0
 #endif
```

Can anyone please help me with this and tell me how can I define a conditional integer value in pch file and use it in the m file.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Neha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put another set of () around your #define like this

```
#define IS_IPHONE5_MAR  (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 568) ? 80 : 0)
```